# How to put multiple p-tags containing multi-line text together (side by side) in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want exactly something like the following:
[Side by side p-tages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k6Fs.png)

Several texts that may be more than one line, and after the end of each `<p></p>` tag there is a shape (circle) and the next text starts from its continuation.

I tried putting inline style to each element but it didn't work well!

```html
/*The div tag is related to the circle shape*/

<p style="display: inline">This is a Lorem ipsum</p>
<div style="display: inline"></div>
<p style="display: inline">dolor sit amet</p>
<div style="display: inline"></div>
<p style="display: inline">elit sed do</p>
<div style="display: inline"></div>
<p style="display: inline">eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
<div style="display: inline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `span` to put elements inside a `p`. Example:

```
<p style="display: inline">
This is a Lorem ipsum <span class="circle"></span>
dolor sit amet <span class="circle"></span>
elit sed do <span class="circle"></span>
eiusmod tempor incididunt <span class="circle"></span>
</p>
```

And in your css file:

```
.circle {
   background-color:gray;
   height:10px;
   width:10px;
   border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the best solution for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Since your div is an **inline element**, it will take the width of the content. Since, the content is empty, the div will not have width.
Make the display **style of your div to inline-block**; Also, add following style to test. It worked for me.

```css
div {
    background-color: gray;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The divs need to be inline-block so they pickup dimensions.

This snippet positions them in two ways: gives the p elements some l/r margins to create a bit of space and translates the div so the circle looks more in line with the characters.

All the sizing and psitioning is done in terms of the prevailing em size so this code scales if that changes.

```css
p,
p+div {
  /* for demo */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

div {
  background-color: #d8e5e9;
  width: 2em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

</style>
```

```html
<p style="display: inline">This is a Lorem ipsum</p>
<div style="display: inline-block"></div>
<p style="display: inline">dolor sit amet</p>
<div style="display: inline-block"></div>
<p style="display: inline">elit sed do</p>
<div style="display: inline-block"></div>
<p style="display: inline">eiusmod tempor incididunt</p>
<div style="display:inline-block"></div>
```